# Eclipse - Install New Software not working

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse 3.5(Galileo). When I choose Help-> Install New Software, It does not Popup any dialog box to process further. Is anything I have to check to work on this?

Comment: Check your error log, it should report some error (window -> show view... -> error log)

Comment: What is your operating system? If it is Vista or Win7 - did you start Eclipse as Admin? Otherwise the process might not be allowed to modify its installation directory.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the libraries:

go to:
Properties-> Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Librariy